# Why is lxml html parser not parsing the complete file?

Tags: html, parsing, lxml, elementtree

I am trying to parse a 16Mb html file using lxml. My actual task is to get all the doc tags and for each doc tag if the value of `docno` tag matches my doc list I extract the content of doc tag.

`self.doc_file_list` is a list containing paths of such 16Mb files that I need to parse.
file is absolute path of the file.

This is the code I am using currently

```
for file in file(self.doc_file_list,'r'):
    tree = etree.parse(file.strip(), parser)
    doc = tree.findall('.//doc')
    for elem in doc:
        docno = elem.find('.//docno').text
        if docno in self.doc_set:
            print >> out, etree.tostring(elem)
```

I checked the content of tree using etree.tostring(tree) and it does not parse the complete file and only parses some kb of the actual file.

Note: I am not getting any error message but the parsed content of tree is incomplete so I am not able to get the whole list.

Comment: Much cleared with the edit indeed. Well, I guess it would help to see an actual example file where the issue shows. Or, alternately, attempt by yourself to find where it stops parsing and see if something's wrong there. See if the issue persists when removing stuff before / after where it stops. Eventually you should be able to narrow it down to a specific problematic construction.

Comment: …and if you find out file size actually is an issue (could be if you're on a small system, loading a 16MB file with libxml will usually eat ~100MB), perhaps use the XmlTextReader API instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this problem. I checked the tree generated and it was not parsing the whole document. This is because the document was heavily broken. You can check this information on the link: lxml.de/parsing.html (removed http as stackoverflow did not let me add more than 2 links). 

 This issue of broken html document can be resolved using one of the following two approaches:

1. Instead of using html parser you can either use ElementSoup provided by lxml. It uses BeautifulSoup parser to handle broken html docs. Link: http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html

**Note: This approach did not work out for me.**

2. Another approach is to directly use BeautifulSoup directly and using the parsers provided by it. There are many parser options provided and you need to find out which one suits you the best. For me, html.parser worked.
Link: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes

Thanks all for the help.